# How to use pomless tycho artifacts in non-tycho project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I have two projects:

1. An Eclipse project build with pomless Tycho approach
2. A plain Java project build with plain Maven, no OSGI, no Tycho

I need to use some of the bundles from the 1st project in the 2nd project. I tried to install the jar files from the 1st project into a local maven repository using `mvn clean install`. And tried to reference them from the 2nd project. But I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal on project ...: Could not resolve dependencies for project ...: Failed to collect dependencies at bpms:bpms.util.jdk:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for bpms:bpms.util.jdk:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find bpms:bundles:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, the resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The `bpms.util.jdk-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom` file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>bpms</groupId>
    <artifactId>bundles</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..\.polyglot.pom.tycho</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>bpms.util.jdk</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
  <name>jdk utils</name>
</project>
```

It seems that the problem is caused by the parent artifact. Is it possible to install my artifacts as standalone artifacts without reference to parent `bundles`?

What is the right approach? I can't use a pomless Tycho and should define a separate pom.xml for each bundle?

Comment: I doubt it will work that way (since a Maven repository is a different thing than a p2 repository). Please link to the documentation that says so. Tycho stores/caches the bundle JARs in the Maven repository in `/p2/osgi/bundle/`. In your second project, have you tried referencing the JARs via [`<systemPath>${settings.localRepository}/p2/osgi/bundle/<path-to-the-jar>.jar</systemPath>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54146663/6505250)?

Comment: No, I installed bundles into `~/.m2` folder using `mvn clean install` and referenced them just as usual maven `<dependency>`. Folder `~/.p2` or a similar one doesn't contain my bundles.

Comment: It seems that the simplest approach is to install all jar files using `mvn install:install-file`. And don't use `mvn clean install`

Comment: That is not what I said nor asked. I guess your assumption is wrong that in a Tycho build `mvn clean install` does more than `mvn clean verify`. As far as I know, the p2 bundle artifacts are stored/cached in `~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/`. If `mvn install:install-file` works, add it as self answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the simplest approach is to install jar files using `mvn install:install-file`. Here is a bat-file that could be useful for someone:

```
@echo off

set MVN_HOME=C:/Tools/apache-maven-3.6.3
set BUNDLES_HOME=C:/Work/workspace-bpms-trunk/bundles
set ECLIPSE_HOME=C:/Tools/eclipse/plugins

set PATH=%MVN_HOME%/bin;%PATH%

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%E in (deps.txt) do (
  if exist %BUNDLES_HOME%/%%F (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%G in (%BUNDLES_HOME%/%%F/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) do (
      if "%%G" == "Bundle-Version" (
        call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=%%E -DartifactId=%%F -Dversion=%%~nH-SNAPSHOT -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="%BUNDLES_HOME%/%%F/target/%%F-%%~nH-SNAPSHOT.jar"
      )
    )
  ) else (
    for %%G in (%ECLIPSE_HOME%/%%F_*.jar) do (
      for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%H in ("%%~nG") do (
        call mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=%%E -DartifactId=%%F -Dversion=%%H -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="%ECLIPSE_HOME%/%%~nG.jar"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

It reads `groupId` and `artifactId` from `deps.txt` file of the following format:

```
org.eclipse.ocl:org.eclipse.ocl
org.eclipse.ocl:org.eclipse.ocl.common
org.eclipse.ocl:org.eclipse.ocl.ecore
org.eclipse.ocl:org.eclipse.ocl.pivot
```

At first it tries to find a bundle in `BUNDLES_HOME`. If found then it reads a bundle version from `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and installs jar into a local maven repository. pom-files are generated.

If the bundle not found in `BUNDLES_HOME` then it tries to find it in `ECLIPSE_HOME`.

The second script reads `deps.txt` and generates a list of dependencies for `pom.xml`:

```
@echo off

set BUNDLES_HOME=C:/Work/workspace-bpms-trunk/bundles
set ECLIPSE_HOME=C:/Tools/eclipse/plugins

break > deps-gen.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%E in (deps.txt) do (
  if exist %BUNDLES_HOME%/%%F (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%G in (%BUNDLES_HOME%/%%F/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) do (
      if "%%G" == "Bundle-Version" (
        echo        ^<dependency^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo            ^<groupId^>%%E^</groupId^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo            ^<artifactId^>%%F^</artifactId^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo            ^<version^>%%~nH-SNAPSHOT^</version^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo        ^</dependency^>>> deps-gen.txt
      )
    )
  ) else (
    for %%G in (%ECLIPSE_HOME%/%%F_*.jar) do (
      for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%H in ("%%~nG") do (
        echo        ^<dependency^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo            ^<groupId^>%%E^</groupId^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo            ^<artifactId^>%%F^</artifactId^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo            ^<version^>%%H^</version^>>> deps-gen.txt
        echo        ^</dependency^>>> deps-gen.txt
      )
    )
  )
)
```

A similar installer for Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

BUNDLES_HOME=~/workspaces/workspace-bpms-trunk/bundles
ECLIPSE_PLUGINS=~/.p2/pool/plugins

while IFS=":" read -r group artifact || [ -n "$p" ]; do
  artifact="${artifact//[$'\r\n']}"
  if [ "$artifact" = "" ]; then
    :
  elif [ -d "$BUNDLES_HOME/$artifact" ]; then
    while IFS=":" read -r key value || [ -n "$p" ]; do
      if [ "$key" = "Bundle-Version" ]; then
        version="${value//[[:space:]]/}"
        version="${version/.qualifier/-SNAPSHOT}"
        mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=$group -DartifactId=$artifact \
          -Dversion=$version -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar \
          -Dfile="$BUNDLES_HOME/$artifact/target/$artifact-$version.jar"
      fi
    done < "$BUNDLES_HOME/$artifact/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
  else
    for file in "$ECLIPSE_PLUGINS"/${artifact}_*.jar; do
      version="${file%%.jar}"
      version="${version##*_}"
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=$group -DartifactId=$artifact \
        -Dversion=$version -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="$file"
    done
  fi
done < deps.txt
```

And pom-file dependency generator:

```
#!/bin/bash

BUNDLES_HOME=~/workspaces/workspace-bpms-trunk/bundles
ECLIPSE_PLUGINS=~/.p2/pool/plugins

: > deps-gen.txt

while IFS=":" read -r group artifact || [ -n "$p" ]; do
  artifact="${artifact//[$'\r\n']}"
  if [ "$artifact" = "" ]; then
    echo >> deps-gen.txt
  elif [ -d "$BUNDLES_HOME/$artifact" ]; then
    while IFS=":" read -r key value || [ -n "$p" ]; do
      if [ "$key" = "Bundle-Version" ]; then
        version="${value//[[:space:]]/}"
        version="${version/.qualifier/-SNAPSHOT}"
        echo "        <dependency>" >> deps-gen.txt
        echo "            <groupId>$group</groupId>" >> deps-gen.txt
        echo "            <artifactId>$artifact</artifactId>" >> deps-gen.txt
        echo "            <version>$version</version>" >> deps-gen.txt
        echo "        </dependency>" >> deps-gen.txt
      fi
    done < "$BUNDLES_HOME/$artifact/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
  else
    for file in "$ECLIPSE_PLUGINS"/${artifact}_*.jar; do
      version="${file%%.jar}"
      version="${version##*_}"
      echo "        <dependency>" >> deps-gen.txt
      echo "            <groupId>$group</groupId>" >> deps-gen.txt
      echo "            <artifactId>$artifact</artifactId>" >> deps-gen.txt
      echo "            <version>$version</version>" >> deps-gen.txt
      echo "        </dependency>" >> deps-gen.txt
    done
  fi
done < deps.txt
```